# HOW CAN I SOLVE ERROR IN INSTALING Adafruit_DHT

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi

ERROR SHOWN IN PROGRAM:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting Adafruit_Python_DHT
  Downloading Adafruit_Python_DHT-1.4.0.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Adafruit_Python_DHT
  Building wheel for Adafruit_Python_DHT (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Ã— python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  â”‚ exit code: 1
  â•°â”€> [1 lines of output]
      Could not detect if running on the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black.  If this failure is unexpected, you can run again with --force-pi or --force-bbb parameter to force using the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black respectively.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Adafruit_Python_DHT
  Running setup.py clean for Adafruit_Python_DHT
Failed to build Adafruit_Python_DHT
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Adafruit_Python_DHT, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

TO SOLVE THE ERROR.
CONTINUE THE PROGRAM

Comment: "Could not detect if running on the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black.  If this failure is unexpected, you can run again with --force-pi or --force-bbb parameter to force using the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black respectively." Have you tried this?

Comment: Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Adafruit_DHT--force-pi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Adafruit_DHT--force-pi